# Changing selectedIndex in TabView doesn't change the visible Tab

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

My template include this rows

```
<TabView selectedIndex="activeTabIndex" @selectedIndexChange="onTabChange">
```

I initially added this:

```
 onTabChange(tab) {
            this.activeTabIndex = tab.value;
 }
```

What I obtained is that: when user tap a tab title, the tab showed changes, if needed, to reflect the one tapped by the user.

Ok until now.

Then I added

```
        onTodoCircleTap(item) {
            const index = this.todos.indexOf(item);
            this.dones.unshift(item);
            this.todos.splice(index, 1);
            this.activeTabIndex = 1;
        },
```

I am sure, using console.log, that when this event is fired, the activeIndex changes, if needed, from 0, the first tab, to 1, the second tab, or viceversa, of course.

But in this case, `TabView` is not updated, or, well, the visible tab of TabView doesn't change to reflect the activeTabIndex.

What am I doing wrong?

> Note: I'am at step 13/29 of online official tutorial on the official playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, I already find my own fault

I need to change

```
<TabView selectedIndex="activeTabIndex"
```

into

```
<TabView :selectedIndex="activeTabIndex"
```

Note the '`:`' char in front of `selectedIndex`